# elongated footprint pads for LGA, BGA, QFN packages

Tags: soldering, footprint, pad

Sometimes I need to add more solder in between a capsule and its land patterns, other times I even need to remove some. It would be much easier if the footprint pads were protruding out from underneath the capsule. Would this have any sort of ill effects for the different no-lead capsule kinds, especially BGA ?

I am particularly concerned with the oven, it has a huge temperature gradient from one corner to another. So maybe the chips will twist on the footprint ? Then again, only need these elongated pads for an 12-LGA / 12-BGA.

Comment: Umm... how would you add or remove solder with BGA package?! 8O

Comment: @Maple with great difficulty :D